# Next.js API functions run multiple times on one call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I am using a Next.js API call to retrieve some data from an external API (I know this is better done with getStaticProps but I need to make a few calls before passing the data to the client.)
I don't understand why doe the backend function runs multiple times, and on the first time it doesn't have the POST data.

cleint

```js
export default function Customer () {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id: submissionId } = router.query

  const { data: customer, error } = useSWR(['/api/jotform/get-client/', submissionId], fetcher)
...
```

server

```js
export default async function handler (req, res) {
  try {
    const customers = await axios.get('https://api.jotform.com/form/' + jotformAPI.form_id + '/submissions?apiKey=' + jotformAPI.key)

    const { submissionId } = req.body
    const customer = customers.data.content.find(client => client.id === submissionId)
    if (!customer) throw new Error('contact does not exist')
    //on the first call the error is triggered, only on the second time I get the data.
...
```

Comment: In your customers page you could add an state variable like this ```const [hasRendered, setHasRendered] = useState(false)``` and then in your ```useSwr(!hasRendered ? ['/api/jotform/get-client/', submissionId] : null, fetcher)```. Then you need to set the variable on first render with ```useEffect(() => { setHasRendered(true)}, [])```

Comment: `submissionId` will be undefined on the page's first render. You should conditional call `useSWR` fetcher function, e.g. `useSWR(submissionId ? ['/api/jotform/get-client/', submissionId] : null, fetcher)`.